# ORA-02019 Error When Executing Queries on Remote Oracle DB in Django Application

Tags: django, oracle, cx-oracle, django-settings, python-oracledb

I'm currently working on a Django application that interacts with an Oracle database. My application needs to execute SQL queries on a remote Oracle database, which is configured in the **settings.py** file.

The SQL queries I'm trying to execute have a syntax similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM table@source
```

Here, source is a different database than the one currently executing the query. Both the source and target databases are Oracle databases.

Despite the remote database being configured in **settings.py**, I encounter the following error when executing the first query:

```
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve this error. Here's some additional information that might be helpful:

I've confirmed that the remote database is accessible outside of the Django environment.
The user credentials used in settings.py have the necessary privileges.
The application works fine with local database queries.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into what might be going wrong? Any advice on configuring Django to work seamlessly with remote Oracle databases using database links would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table@source
```

`@source` means that your client (python/django on your local machine) talks to one database (presumably, in this case, the `target` database) and then that `target` database opens a database link to the `source` database where the `table` table is located and performs the query and then the result set is sent back to the `target` database and then back to the client.

When you use a database link, you are **NOT** connecting directly to the `source` database so anything specified in the `settings.py` is irrelevant.

Either:

- Do not use database links and use:

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM table
  ```

  And tell Django to use the connection to the `source` database that is specified in the `settings.py` (See the [Multiple Databases - Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/multi-db/) for more details); or
- Only specify the `target` database in `settings.py` and [create a database link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html) on `target` to the `source`. Something like:

  ```sql
  CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK source USING 'insert_connection_string';
  ```

  *(Read the documentation link above and adapt as appropriate.)*

  Then you can connect to `target` and use:

  ```sql
  SELECT * FROM table@source
  ```

Comment: I was able to do it a bit differently. But, based on your idea. Thanks mate.

Comment: Got another issue. 
Any idea on this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77832441/how-to-execute-oracle-sql-query-with-multiple-database-links-in-django

@MTO